# Android: Can't mkdir on SD-Card

Tags: android, android-studio, filesystems, mkdir

```
    File newDirFile = new File(newDir);
    int b= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(m_context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    Log.d("Write Permission", Integer.toString(b));
    if (! newDirFile.exists() )
    {
        return newDirFile.mkdir();
    }
```

var b = 0 after checkSelfPermission, what means access is allowed.(Read/Write permissions are granted when starting application)
Making a directory on internal memory is successful(/storage/emulated/0) Making a directory on SD(/storage/xxxx-xxxx/ fails. `newDirFile.mkdir() == 0`
In ADB-shell I can su-less make directories under /storage/xxxx-xxxx/

Comment: You cannot create directories or files in arbitrary locations on removable storage using filesystem APIs, regardless of permissions.

Comment: So, we have here an 'operating-system' where we aren't able to create a folder on a removable drive?

Comment: Well, on Android 10+ you cannot create files in most places. The rules for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) have been in place since Android 5.0 or so. This has been part of a gradual increase in restrictions on apps for better privacy and security, because too many app developers doing too many hostile things.

Comment: Would it be possible with this DocumentFile-api (or with this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-document) ?

Comment: Not directly. You are welcome to use `DocumentFile` in conjunction with the Storage Access Framework API. For example, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose a "document tree" for you to use. `DocumentFile` then lets you use that document tree via a `File`-like API. However, the *user* can decide where that document tree resides. You cannot force the user to place it on removable storage.

Comment: And how do apps like 'TotalCommander' the Job? I remember that this app at first start, showed the build-in file-explorer from Android, then the user had to select the root-directory of the SD-card. After that, the TotalCommand had a lifetime RW-access to the SD-card.

Comment: That was `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. And you chose to select the root directory of a removable storage volume.

Comment: From user xmen: "Sometimes things turns out to be as never intended. But that doesn't mean it will always be bad. Most of android users like android just because it has many free apps available, and the reason behind many applications was because android used to be very open. Now they keep closing their main feature one by one. Soon it will be same as windows phone and iPhone. Android does allows to user to install APK from outside Google Play, and it warns them before. Couldn't they do same with this ? And all the excuses they coming up with clean and secure, its all moronic."